# How to convert String and date time in java

Tags: java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi everyone i used bootstrap date time picker to save date and time when i select the date in jsp. am getting date and time as a String in java class like this **23 January 2017 - 02:50 pm** am trying to convert this to date is not working where i need to change

```
$(function () {     
   $('#datetimepicker8').datetimepicker({           
      startDate: new Date(),
      format   : 'dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p',
      autoclose: 1,
   }).on( 'changeDate', function(e) {
      // Revalidate the date field
      $('#timeTableUpdateForm').bootstrapValidator(
         'revalidateField', 'examDate');
   });
});
```

.

```
public class StringToDate {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SimpleDateFormat formatter =
         new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy-HH:mm:ss a");
      String dateInString = "23 January 2017 - 02:50 pm";
      try {
         Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
         System.out.println(date);
         System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
      }
      catch( ParseException e ) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: In addition to below answers, it appears to be depending on language whether it gets parsed or not. Beeing German it only worked out when using `Januar` instead of `January`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code:

```
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      final SimpleDateFormat formatter =
         new SimpleDateFormat( "dd MMMMM yyyy - HH:mm a", Locale.US );
      final String dateInString = "23 January 2017 - 02:50 pm";
      try {
         final Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
         System.out.println(date);
         System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
      }
      catch( final ParseException e ) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

With this output :

```
Mon Jan 23 02:50:00 CET 2017
23 January 2017 - 02:50 AM
```

Comment: Mon Jan 23 00:00:00 IST 2017    for this date.getYear is not working

Comment: Please give the `dateInString` value to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Two errors here:

1. A space is missing between year and dash - dash and hour
2. You are telling java to parse seconds, but you don't have seconds in your date string.

You need to change your SimpleDateFormat from

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy-HH:mm:ss a");
```

To

```
// Added two spaces and removed seconds from format, added Locale
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy - HH:mm a", Locale.US);
//                                                             ^ ^     ^
```

By changing your code this way I get this output:

```
Mon Jan 23 02:50:00 GMT 2017
23 January 2017 - 02:50 AM
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/bpCv73)

Comment: `, Locale.US` should be added to `SimpleDateFormat` ctor when executed in a non US os